# error in my AVR PWM library code

Tags: c++, avr

Hi I am creating a PWM library in c++ to use in my project. I have started working on it below is part of my code it is not complete yet. I have writing a bit by bit code and building it to find errors and I found some error so I stopped. Even though I had defined right parameters it is giving error. It should preprocess first #if and assign TCC0A with 0x80. But it skipping #if, #elif and last #else is execuing. Please help me to correct given code.

IDE: Atmel Studio 7.0

MCU: ATmega328p

Code:

```
/************************************************************ 
PWM.h file
************************************************************/

#ifndef PWM_H_
#define PWM_H_

//PWM outputs
#define OC0A 1
#define OC0B 2

//PWM modes
#define NINV 0b10000000      //Non-inverting Mode
#define INV  0b11000000      //Inverting Mode

#include <avr/io.h>

class PWM
{ 
public:
void Initialize(unsigned char PWMoutputpin,  unsigned char PWMmode)
{
TCCR0A = 0x00; TCCR0B = 0x00;
#if ((PWMoutputpin == OC0A) && (PWMmode == NINV))
      TCCR0A |= NINV;

#elif ((PWMoutputpin == OC0A) && (PWMmode == INV))
      TCCR0A |= INV;

#elif ((PWMoutputpin == OC0B) && (PWMmode == NINV))
      TCCR0A |= (NINV >> 2);

#elif ((PWMoutputpin == OC0B) && (PWMmode == INV))
      TCCR0A |= (INV >> 2);

#else
  #error PWM::Initialize() parameters not defined properly.
#endif
}
};
#endif /* PWM_H_ */

/******************************* END **********************/


/************************************************************
main.cpp file
************************************************************/
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "PWM.h"

int main(void)
{
PWM p;                    //define PWM as p object
p.Initialize(OC0A,NINV);  //initialize PWM with OC0A as output with non-inverting mode
return 0;
}
```

Comment: #if is a **pre-processor** directive. Do you expect the compiler to know what you pass to `p.Initialize` when including `PWM.h`? Since PWM.h is included before the call, it just simply _cannot_... Here, have a closer look at the docs for #if, #elif, #else, and #endif Directives: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew2hz0yd.aspx

Comment: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_port_pass

Answer (score 0):

As commented on already you cannot use `#if` the way you are. The compiler can only make a decision once at compile time when executing the `#if` statement. You are trying to use the `#if` statement based on a changing parameter input, or run-time. The `#if` cannot be used at run-time when your library code is being called by another function, at this point compiling has already finished.

#### Code Change

Your code should be changed to:

```
void Initialize(unsigned char PWMoutputpin,  unsigned char PWMmode)
{
  TCCR0A = 0x00; TCCR0B = 0x00;

  if ((PWMoutputpin == OC0A) && (PWMmode == NINV))
      TCCR0A |= NINV;
  else if ((PWMoutputpin == OC0A) && (PWMmode == INV))
      TCCR0A |= INV;
  else if ((PWMoutputpin == OC0B) && (PWMmode == NINV))
      TCCR0A |= (NINV >> 2);
  else if ((PWMoutputpin == OC0B) && (PWMmode == INV))
      TCCR0A |= (INV >> 2);
  else
      // #error PWM::Initialize() parameters not defined properly.
      // Your error output message can be sent by `cout` or some
      // other method like `assert()`.
}
```

#### More Code Changes

You could even simplify your code even further. Notice how if your output pin is `OC0A` that the `TCCR0A` value is just `or`'d with the PWM mode? Same is true for `OC0B`:

```
void Initialize(unsigned char PWMoutputpin,  unsigned char PWMmode)
{
  TCCR0A = 0x00; TCCR0B = 0x00;

  if (PWMoutputpin == OC0A)
      TCCR0A |= PWMmode;
  else if (PWMoutputpin == OC0B)
      TCCR0A |= (PWMmode >> 2);
  else
      // #error PWM::Initialize() parameters not defined properly.
      // Your error output message can be sent by `cout` or some
      // other method like `assert()`.
}
```

This assumes only two modes/values of `NINV` and `INV` will be passed in. If a user passes in another value then you'll get some weird results but you can also check for `PWMmode` before the `if` statements to make sure it is valid.